# Visual studio 2013 ultimate, WebMatrix 3 and WAMP server in same machine

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio

I want to use Visual studio 2013 ultimate and WebMatrix 3 in the same machine that i run WAMP server on it, but some problem happen to WAMP server and (IIS when test using Webmatrix) if i do this, Please i need a solution to run them all without using virtual machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much to go on there, "some problem"? More detail is needed.

The first thing that springs to mind is that you are trying to run Apache and IIS at the same time listening on the same ports. Either change one of them or only run one at a time.

In theory, other than the ports, it should be possible. The only other thing I can think of is that one of the installations overrides a key library that the other wont work with.

Comment: i think the problem always come from ruining Apache and IIS at the same time, i will test and see, thanks

Comment: OK, by default both will be set up to use ports 80 and 443. On one of them, change the defaults to 8080 and 8443 or some such. You will, of course, have to remember to use the ports in URLs when testing.